# Not able to create column and row in flutter listview

Tags: flutter

I am beginner to flutter and I am trying to add the new column, first one is default visible and the second one is visible (this is needs to be done, I have already have the code but before adding things, I am trying to set it up) by the action. So I have updated code with columns, but if I do that, all the cards are displaying as empty, not sure where I am making issue

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var img = widget.data['password'];
    return Card(
      // borderOnForeground: true,
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 55, 55),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        side: const BorderSide(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 60, 60, 60),
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              left: BorderSide(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 143, 175, 112), width: 10),
            ),
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 242, 241, 241),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          // alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Container(
                    // child: Column( //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!If I add this line of code to make two columns it is displaying only the above container
                    children: [
                    Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 9,
                      child: Container(
                        child: Column(children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/bank_logos/$img.png',
                            height: 60,
                          ),

                          // Icon(
                          //   Icons.card_membership,
                          //   color: Color.fromARGB(255, 183, 183, 183),
                          //   size: 50.0,
                          //   semanticLabel:
                          //       'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                          // ),
                          const Spacer(),
                          Text(img),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: CustomPaint(painter: DashedLinePainter()),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    const Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.person,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 93, 93),
                          size: 22.0,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text("Hussain"),
                        SizedBox(width: 15),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.content_copy,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 168, 168, 168),
                          size: 18.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 93, 93),
                          size: 22.0,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 5),
                        const Text("*****"),
                        const SizedBox(width: 15),
                        IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print("copied");
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(
                            Icons.content_copy,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 168, 168, 168),
                            size: 18.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please do the CTRL+F with `!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!If I add this line` in this page, so it will highlight the issue in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two nested columns:

```dart
Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Column(
                  // ---> Column 1
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 9,
                          child: Container(
                            child: Column(// ---> Column 2
                                children: [
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
```

The quickest solution would be set a fixed height for the second column.

You can wrap a `SizedBox()` and add a height.

Or, since you already have an unused container right above the Column2, you can just add a fixed height:

```dart
Expanded(
                flex: 4,
                child: Column(
                  // ---> Column 1
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 9,
                          child: Container(
                            // ---> Add a fixed height container
                            height: 100,
                            child: Column(// ---> Column 2
                                children: [
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will work.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var img = widget.data['password'];
    return Card(
      borderOnForeground: true,
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 55, 55, 55),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        side: const BorderSide(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 60, 60, 60),
          width: 1.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipPath(
        clipper: ShapeBorderClipper(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              left: BorderSide(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 143, 175, 112), width: 10),
            ),
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 242, 241, 241),
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          // alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Column(children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        const Text('Image should be here'),
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/bank_logos/$img.png',
                          height: 60,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.card_membership,
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 183, 183, 183),
                          size: 50.0,
                          semanticLabel:
                              'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                        ),
                        const Spacer(),
                        Text(img),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      ]),
                    ),
                    CustomPaint(painter: DashedLinePainter())
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Column(children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                const Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 93, 93),
                      size: 22.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),
                    Text("Hussain"),
                    SizedBox(width: 15),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.content_copy,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 168, 168, 168),
                      size: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.lock,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 93, 93, 93),
                      size: 22.0,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    const Text("*****"),
                    const SizedBox(width: 15),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("copied");
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.content_copy,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 168, 168, 168),
                        size: 18.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens mostly because `ListView`, `Row` and `Column` try to grow as much as they can when you put a `ListView` as child of a `Column` or a `Column` as child of `ListView` without constraints they would grow to infinity and it's not good.
some ways of putting constraints is wrapping child with `SizedBox` or `Container` and giving a constraint height or width.
Also if `Column` is used as child you can use `mainAxisSize` property and set it to minimum size : `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you've used the `Expanded` widget to create the two columns. The issue might be related to the structure of your widget tree. You are using an `Expanded` widget inside another `Expanded` widget, which can sometimes lead to layout issues.

1. `Remove` the extra `Expanded` `widget`: It seems you have an extra `Expanded` widget wrapping your entire `Row` widget. Try removing the outer `Expanded` widget and see if it resolves the issue.

```
child: Container(
  // Remove the outer Expanded widget
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        // Your existing code
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

2. Ensure that the inner `Row` has MainAxisAlignment set: Make sure you set the mainAxisAlignment property of your inner Row widget. This property determines how the children should be placed along the main axis (horizontal axis in your case).

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // Adjust as needed
  children: [
    // Your existing code
  ],
),
```

3. Check for errors in the console: Look for any error messages or warnings in the console. Flutter usually provides helpful messages that can guide you in identifying layout issues.
4. Check the DashedLinePainter and other custom widgets: Ensure that your custom widgets (DashedLinePainter and others) are implemented correctly and are not causing any rendering issues.